# different import and export form of typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am a novoice in typescript. Can anyone explain to me the difference between these export:

```
export default class Foo {}
/* or */
class Foo {}
export = Foo;
/* or */
export class Foo { }
```

And the difference between these form of import:

```
import x = require('y');
import x from 'y';
import { x } from 'y'
import * as x from 'y';
```

And when to use each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all covered in the [modules docs page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

**[Default exports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#default-exports)**

```
export default class Foo {}
// and
import x from 'y';
```

> Each module can optionally export a default export. Default exports
>   are marked with the keyword default; and there can only be one default
>   export per module. default exports are imported using a different
>   import form.

**[Export =](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)**

```
export = Foo;
// and
import x = require('y');
```

> Both CommonJS and AMD generally have the concept of an exports object
>   which contains all exports from a module.
>
> They also support replacing the exports object with a custom single
>   object. Default exports are meant to act as a replacement for this
>   behavior; however, the two are incompatible. TypeScript supports
>   export = to model the traditional CommonJS and AMD workflow.
>
> The export = syntax specifies a single object that is exported from
>   the module. This can be a class, interface, namespace, function, or
>   enum.
>
> When importing a module using export =, TypeScript-specific import let
>   = require("module") must be used to import the module.

The other forms you included:

```
export class Foo { }
// and
import { x } from 'y'
import * as x from 'y';
```

Are the normal form of [export](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export) and [import](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import).
It is based on the es6 import/export syntax, you can find more info in MDN as well: [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) / [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).